# why my old password would not change to new password

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my members table the password is all in md5

```
ID username password
100  alex     alex
```

this is my changepassword.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysql_select_db("lecturer",$conn);
$myid = $_GET["myid"];
if(count($_POST)>0) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from members WHERE ID=' . $myid . '");
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if (md5($_POST["currentPassword"]) == md5($row["password"])) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE members set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "' WHERE ID=' . $myid . '");
    $message = "Password Changed";
  } else $message = "Current Password is not correct";
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Change Password</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script>
function validatePassword() {
  var currentPassword,newPassword,confirmPassword,output = true;

  currentPassword = document.frmChange.currentPassword;
  newPassword = document.frmChange.newPassword;
  confirmPassword = document.frmChange.confirmPassword;

  if(!currentPassword.value) {
    currentPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("currentPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
  }
  else if(!newPassword.value) {
    newPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("newPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
  }
  else if(!confirmPassword.value) {
    confirmPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
  }
  if(newPassword.value != confirmPassword.value) {
    newPassword.value="";
    confirmPassword.value="";
    newPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "not same";
    output = false;
  }     
  return output;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmChange" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return validatePassword()">
<div style="width:500px;">
<div class="message"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" class="tblSaveForm">
<tr class="tableheader">
<td colspan="2">Change Password</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40%"><label>Current Password</label></td>
<td width="60%"><input type="password" name="currentPassword" class="txtField"/><span id="currentPassword"  class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>New Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="newPassword" class="txtField"/><span id="newPassword" class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<td><label>Confirm Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="txtField"/><span id="confirmPassword" class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body></html>
```

when i enter as ID=100 and i wanted to change the password alex to alex123 but i kept getting my current password is not correct.
what did i done wrong in my code???

thank you

Comment: `$_POST["newPassword"]` is encrypted or storing as plain text?

Comment: Just a quick question, if the password in your table is already stored in md5 format, why this line `if (md5($_POST["currentPassword"]) == md5($row["password"]))`  ? It should be `if (md5($_POST["currentPassword"]) == $row["password"])`

Comment: You have an sql injection hole.

Comment: [consider indenting your code nicely](http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/)

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that everything is wrong with your code. You don't really store hashed passwords, you compare password hashes in a pointless way. You have a huge SQL injection problem, you use mysql_ instead of mysqli_ or PDO, and you don't catch errors in your SQL queries. This has to be rethought from the very beginning.

Comment: and mysql is deprecated, use mysqli instead

Answer (score 1):

use only

> == ($row["password"])) {

because your stored password is already encoded

Comment: why would that fix the issue?